# vue and route error laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i've error with route and vue file , when i submit the form it gives me **MethodNotAllowedHttpException** and i've checked everything but can not get the error...

web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::post('addServices','Services/ServicesController@createServices');
```

addservices.vue

```
    <template>
    <form class="form-vertical" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="label-control">اسم الخدمة</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" v-model="name" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="image" class="label-control">معرض الخدمة</label>
            <input type="file" id="image" v-el:image>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="body" class="label-control">وصف الخدمة</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" cols="4" rows="10" name="body" id="body" v-model="body"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="category_id" class="label-control">التصنيف</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="category_id" id="category_id" v-model="category_id">
                <option>آختر التصنيف</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="price" class="label-control">السعر</label>
            <input type="number" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" v-model="price">
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" @click="AddThisServices()" name="submit" value="اضافة الخدمة" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function(){
            return{
                name: '',
                image: '',
                body: '',
                category_id: '',
                price: ''
            }
        },
        methods:{
            AddThisServices: function(){
                const formdata = new FormData();
                formdata.append('name', this.name);
                formdata.append('image', this.$els.image.files[0]);
                formdata.append('body', this.body);
                formdata.append('category_id', this.category_id);
                formdata.append('price', this.price);
                this.sendData(formdata);
            },
            sendData: function(){
                this.$http.post('/addServices', formdata).then(function(response){

                }, function (response){

                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

i'm waiting forward to know what's the problem because i'm new in laravel and i've searched a lot about it , but i could not find any problem about this , help me guys!

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap.js');

import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
Vue.use(VueResource);

Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.getElementById('_token').getAttribute('value');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const AddServices = require('./components/services/addservices.vue');
const MyServices = require('./components/services/myservices.vue');
const IncomeOrders = require('./components/orders/incomeorders.vue');
const SendOrders = require('./components/orders/sendorders.vue');

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component:{ template: "<p>home</p>"} },
        { path: '/AddServices', component: AddServices },
        { path: '/IncomeOrders', component: IncomeOrders },
        { path: '/SendOrders', component: SendOrders }
    ]
});
const app = new Vue({ router }).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `/` in your route

```
Route::post('/addServices','Services/ServicesController@createServices');
```

I suggest to put this route in your `api.php` as this api for now and call as `/api/addServices` and then in future use `auth:api` with token

Comment: there is : <meta name="csrf-token" id="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
in the app.blade.php 
i've tried your codes and did not change anything , the same problem

Comment: @AliHarb : May problem is here , you not getting `formdata` so add this here `sendData: function(formdata){`

Comment: Or you can also try by directly pass `_token` in your `formdata` as `formdata.append('price',$("input[name='_token']").val().trim());`

Comment: try your data in your controller as `return dd($request->all())` and check this in your network tab in your browser and share ?

Comment: i tried this before : formdata.append('csrf-token',$("input[name='_token']").val().trim‌​());

Comment: i just get MethodNotAllowedHttpException with nothing else

Comment: OMG :: just try `/` in your route. `Route::post('/addServices','Services/ServicesController@createServices');`

Comment: How fool I am. I was reading this error as `TokenNotFound`/`TokenMismatch` error

Comment: hahahah xd i've noticed but i wanted to do your way xddd
anyway i've try to add / before but with no sense :\

Comment: I suggest to put this route in your `api.php` as this api for now and call as `/api/addServices` and then in future use `auth:api` with token

Comment: i even tried to change the route for /home instead of addservices but it did not work

Comment: where should i call it /api/addServices? which file?

Comment: Inside `sendData` method, where you are calling post ajax

Comment: the same :\ no sense

Comment: Do you have any middleware in your controller ?

Comment: public function createServices(Request $request){
        dd($request->all());
    }

Comment: i had error in my route , missing servicescontroller but i edited it and now the routes work fine but still the same error xd

Comment: well , i've fixed the problem finally xd after 10 hours hahah 
anyway there is a problem in uploading picture using vue , it says undifend el , its about el:image in the input , do you've any idea how can i make the file input?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this will help:

```
<form class="form-vertical" v-on:submit.prevent="AddThisServices()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="label-control">اسم الخدمة</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" v-model="name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image" class="label-control">معرض الخدمة</label>
        <input type="file" id="image" v-el:image>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body" class="label-control">وصف الخدمة</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" cols="4" rows="10" name="body" id="body" v-model="body"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category_id" class="label-control">التصنيف</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="category_id" id="category_id" v-model="category_id">
            <option>آختر التصنيف</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price" class="label-control">السعر</label>
        <input type="number" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" v-model="price">
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="اضافة الخدمة" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: the same problem